# I'm having issues makin a simple input and output program

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

Okay So I work visual c# when i want to put this line

```
enter code here




static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.ReadLine a, b, c, max;

        }
    }
}
```

but it says this error about the ReadLine part:
The type name "ReadLine" does not exist in the type 'Console'

Comment: What should I do about it?

Comment: looks like you have already asked the same question in `Java`. What's your final goal here? learning both?

Comment: @Rahul That was for a very long time ago and i wasn't learning java serious but i'm learning this one more serious and man you're stubborn xD ;)

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to use this command for int numbers? i want to get a program that gets numbers and tells you which one is higher i just need help for the input part.

Comment: You need to convert the data to INT type. Start reading documentation ... by asking question no one learns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Console.ReadLine is a method, so it should be used like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter something"); //this will print the text to the screen
string inputText = Console.ReadLine(); // Get string from the input and assign it to the inputText variable
```

You can see an additional reference [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

What's This??? Go and read MSDN documentation first. The error is cause `ReadLine()` is a method but you are trying to use it as a type by itself. It should just be below assuming you have already declared a variable named `a` and it's of type `string`.

```
a = Console.ReadLine();
```

Read [Console.ReadLine Method ()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx). documentation has few good examples which will help in clear your doubts.

Comment: @user3607864, consider accepting the answer if it's helpful.